# need help pulling all xml data from query result and moving into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

My second time on here and thanks for all the help on my last question!

I have a simple query that gives me and item id and its specifics. The specifics are xml. I need to get the xml data into a table but with association to the id number.
There are different names in the xml's but i need to make those the column headers.

The query is

```
select 
    ListingEbayID, ItemSpecifics
from 
    ListingsEbay
```

there is a pic of the results

!(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/--OfYRsyrH9M/U0bHyNTBGAI/AAAAAAAABvA/oQlJjE3I3fM/w762-h132-no/query.jpg)

and this is the xml data in 1 column, item id (1)

```
<SelectedValues>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Interchange Part Number</Name>
    <Value>638-57121</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Inventory ID</Name>
    <Value>108470</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Year</Name>
    <Value>1997</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Model</Name>
    <Value>LEXUS SC300</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Stock Number</Name>
    <Value>W11218</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Conditions and Options</Name>
    <Value>PIONEER AMP OEM 86280-24111</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Part Number</Name>
    <Value>108470</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Brand</Name>
    <Value>LEXUS</Value>
  </SelectedValue>
  <SelectedValue>
    <Name>Item Condition</Name>
    <Value>Used</Value>
    <ValueID>3000</ValueID>
  </SelectedValue>
</SelectedValues>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the details for a given entry like this:

```
SELECT 
    Name = XC.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    Value = XC.value('(Value)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    ValueID = XC.value('(ValueID)[1]', 'int')
FROM 
    dbo.ListingsEbay
CROSS APPLY 
    ItemSpecifics.nodes('/SelectedValues/SelectedValue') AS XT(XC)
WHERE
    ID = 1
```

Now that you have your data as a relational row/column set of data, you can do anything with it.

Comment: thats on the path, but i need the names to be the table header and the value to be in the field

Comment: [link](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-5xsZ4FTsZIw/U0bd49rVUjI/AAAAAAAAAQc/xZDAcPRr3gA/w898-h721-no/query2.jpg) is a pic of the results, there is different names in the xml's but i need to make those the column headers.

Comment: You cannot do this in SQL Server's XQuery, sorry.